# reading large file, wrong file size

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to read a large file from a disk and report percentage while it's loading. The problem is FileInfo.Length is reporting different size than my Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes().Length.

```
    public void loadList()
    {
        string ListPath = InnerConfig.dataDirectory + core.operation[operationID].Operation.Trim() + "/List.txt";
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(ListPath);

        int bytesLoaded = 0;

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(ListPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
                bytesLoaded += array.Length;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(bytesLoaded + "/" + f.Length);
    }
```

The result is

```
    13357/15251
```

There's 1900 bytes 'missing'. The file contains list of short strings. Any tips why it's reporting different file sizes? does it has to do anything with '\r' and '\n' characters in the file? In addition, I have the following line:

```
    int bytesLoaded = 0;
```

if the file is lets say 1GB large, do I have to use 'long' instead? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Using `int` or `long` won't make a difference here, see [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx).

Comment: Welcome to the world of character encodings - different languages use different encodings, so not everything is ASCII.

Comment: @Aron using `ReadToEnd` with a **large file** will not be a good idea. You can have limit memory problems or LOH fragmentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct; the difference in the reported sizes is due to the newline characters. Per the MSDN documentation on [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx):

> The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed.

Depending on the source which created your file, each [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) would consist of either one or two characters (most commonly: `\r\n` on Windows; just `\n` on Linux).

That said, if your intention is to read the file as a sequence of bytes (without regard to lines), you should use the [`FileStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) method, which avoids the overhead of ASCII encoding (as well as returns the correct count in `total`):

```
byte[] array = new byte[1024];   // buffer
int total = 0;
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(ListPath, FileMode.Open, 
                                 FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    int read;
    while ((read = fs.Read(array, 0, array.Length)) > 0)
    {
        total += read;
        // process "array" here, up to index "read"
    }
}
```

**Edit**: [spender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981354/1149773) raises an important point about character encodings; your code should only be used on ASCII text files. If your file was written using a different encoding – the most popular today being UTF-8 – then results may be incorrect.

Consider, for example, the three-byte hex sequence `E2-98-BA`. `StreamReader`, which uses `UTF8Encoding` by default, would decode this as a single character, `☺`. However, this character cannot be represented in ASCII; thus, calling `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("☺")` would return a *single* byte corresponding to the ASCII value of the fallback character, `?`, thereby leading to loss in character count (as well as incorrect processing of the byte array).

Finally, there is also the possibility of an encoding [preamble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getpreamble.aspx) (such as Unicode byte order marks) at the beginning of the text file, which would also be stripped by the `ReadLine`, resulting in a further discrepancy of a few bytes.

Comment: Thanks! that solved my problem! I gotta wait 8mins to accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

It's the line endings which get swallowed by ReadLine, and could also possibly be because your source file is in a more verbose encoding than ASCII (perhaps it's UTF8?).

`int.MaxValue` is 2147483647, so you're going to run into problem using an `int` for `bytesLoaded` if your file is >2GB. Switch to a `long`. After all, `FileInfo.Length` is defined as a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

The ***ReadLine*** method removes the trailing line termination character.